# Matlab program for the an integral equation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, matlab, greens-function

I am trying to write a matlab program for the an integral equation such as below
\begin{equation}
x(s)-\int_{0}^{1}k(s, t)e^{x(t)}dt = 0 \ \ s \in [0,1],
\end{equation}
where $k(s,t)$ is given as 
\begin{equation}
k(s,t) =  \left \{ \begin{array}{cl} -t(1-s), & {\rm}\ t \leq s,\\
 -s(1-t),& {\rm}\ s < t. \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

A matlab program such as below can be written for $K(x,y),$

syms t s

for i = 1:length(t)

```
for j = 1:length(s)
```

if t<=s ;

ker=-t*(1-s(j));

elseif s < t;

ker=-s*(1-t(i));

end

```
end
```

end